# Problem sending push notification from firebase console to all devices

Tags: android, firebase

I want to manually send a notification from the firebase console to all users but somehow only one user(the first user) is getting a notification.

**My MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @SuppressLint("WrongThread")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel=
                new NotificationChannel(MyNotification.CHANNEL_ID,MyNotification.CHANNEL_NAME,NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationChannel.setDescription(MyNotification.CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION);
        //notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        //notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
}
```

**Notification Manager:**

```
public class MyNotification {
    public static final String CHANNEL_ID="myChannelID";
    public static final String CHANNEL_NAME="myChannelName";
    public static final String CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION="myChannelDescription";
    private Context nCtx;
    private static MyNotification myNotification;
    private MyNotification(Context context){
        nCtx = context;
    }
    public static synchronized MyNotification getInstance(Context context){
        if (myNotification==null){
            myNotification = new MyNotification(context);
        }
        return myNotification;

    }
    public void displayNotification(String title,String body){
        NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(nCtx,CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentText(title)
                .setContentTitle(body);
        Intent intent = new Intent(nCtx,MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(nCtx,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        nBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) nCtx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (notificationManager!=null){
            notificationManager.notify(1,nBuilder.build());
        }
    }
}
```

firebase setting is exactly the same as the guide in the firebase tool.
**Firebase Messaging:**

```
public class FirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        String title="Test";
        String body="Test";
        MyNotification.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).displayNotification(title,body);


    }

}
```

"Note: Somehow the title and body I defined in code above doesn't matter and whatever I write in firebase console will be body and title"

"Note: all androids I'm testing on are oreo or above:
and Firebase settings are exactly the same as the guide in the firebase tool.

what is causing this problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the FCM you need to send a message to a device id, or subscribe a user to a certain topic. You need to send to a topic or group or certain device token.

You cannot just send messages to a device if you don't have the three. It won't work. Follow the following

[Follow this link to know how to fully send a message with FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)